# How to get responsive input element in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, input, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to make `<input type="text"/>` element responsive? something similar to `<img class="img-responsive" src="img.png" />` element.
I want bootstrap to to change width of the input field if it's not fitted in a grid after resize. In other hand this input should have maximum width that could not be exceeded.

Comment: This is where i usually reference when refering to forms. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: Have you tried with grid column ?
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-2">
  </div>

Comment: @Aliassse, I did: in this case it just stretches to the grid cell and I need standard width  of input if there is enough space for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Qvatra Did you use .form-control class on your input? This class sets width to 100%, meaning your input will be responsive if its container is responsive (and I think it is because that's how Bootstrap is built).

Comment: What about range input element? how to make it responsive? .form-control is not an option here...

Comment: @Qvatra The .form-control class can be applied on all html element like this : class="form-control". Have you tried to do this ?

Comment: sure. In the case of range element this class also adds a box around the element and deletes a middle line. Which obvious is not what I want.

Comment: I see. Why not create you own class with only the width property ? And, just for the record, be careful, the range input type is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.